# return numeric(0) in apply function

Tags: r, apply

I have two simple data frames A and B:

```
 A<-data.frame(V1=c(0.25,0.5,0.75,1),V2=c("a","b","c","d"))
 B<-data.frame(V2=c(1,2,3,4))
 rownames(B)=c(0.25,0.5,0.75,1)
```

Now I want to move B to the 3rd column of A according the row names of B. I try `apply()`:

```
A$V3<-apply(A,1,function(x){return(B[rownames(B)==x[1],1])})
```

now A looks like this:

```
    V1 V2 V3
1 0.25  a  1
2 0.50  b 
3 0.75  c  3
4 1.00  d
```

Only if I run the same command again, "2"  and "4" appear in the 3rd column:

```
    V1 V2 V3
1 0.25  a  1
2 0.50  b  2
3 0.75  c  3
4 1.00  d  4
```

It seems it returns numeric(0) in the row 2 and 4 if I only run it once. And I try to delete V2 column in A and run the command just once. Everything is fine. no values missing.

Does anyone know why the values are missing in row 2 and 4 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you're comparing strings, not numerics, when using `apply` in that way.

Notice what is printed

```
z = apply(A,1,function(x){
    print("Next")
    print(rownames(B))
    print(x[1])
    })

[1] "Next"
[1] "0.25" "0.5"  "0.75" "1"
    V1
"0.25"
[1] "Next"
[1] "0.25" "0.5"  "0.75" "1"
    V1
"0.50"
[1] "Next"
[1] "0.25" "0.5"  "0.75" "1"
    V1
"0.75"
[1] "Next"
[1] "0.25" "0.5"  "0.75" "1"
    V1
"1.00"
```

and that

```
"0.5" == "0.50"
[1] FALSE
```

So you'll probably want to properly convert to `numeric` first. Any of these three will work:

```
A$V3 = apply(A,1,function(x){return(B[rownames(B)==as.numeric(x[1]),1])})
A$V3[match(rownames(B), A[,1])] = B[,1]
A$V3 = sapply(A[,1], function(x){return(B[rownames(B)==x[1],1])})
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I thought rownames(B) is strings, so I have tried to use as.charactor() for x[1] so that they can be comparable. I didn't realize it is the other way around. Now I know. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that requires `dplyr` and `tibble`. First, I define the data frames.

```
# Define data frames
A<-data.frame(V1=c(0.25,0.5,0.75,1),V2=c("a","b","c","d"))
B<-data.frame(V2=c(1,2,3,4))
rownames(B)=c(0.25,0.5,0.75,1)
```

Next, I turn `B`'s row names into a column, convert this column to a numeric, and join `B` to `A` using `V1`.

```
B %>% 
  rownames_to_column(var = "V1") %>% 
  mutate(V1 = as.numeric(V1)) %>% 
  right_join(A, by = "V1")

#     V1 V2.x V2.y
# 1 0.25    1    a
# 2 0.50    2    b
# 3 0.75    3    c
# 4 1.00    4    d
```